# React this is undefined when using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

Hey guys trying react out and having an issue when using `setState`, I keep getting Cannot read property `setState` of undefined error and I'm not sure how to fix it. I've tried using bind in the constructor but that still doesn't fix the issue.

Thanks for your input.

```
import React from 'react';

class Products extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props)
 this.state = {products:{}}
 this.getItems = this.getItems.bind(this)
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.getItems('http://lcboapi.com/products/300681').then(function(response){
  console.log(response);
  this.setState({products:response});
},function(error){
  console.log('failed',error);
});
}
componentWillMount() {

}

getItems(url){

return new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('GET',url);
  req.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Token Token');


  req.onload = function(){
    if(req.status == 200){
      resolve(req.response);
    }else{
      reject(Error(req.statusText));
    }
  };

  req.onerror = function(){
    reject(Error("Error"));
  };

  req.send();

});

}

render() {
return (
 <div>
  hi
 </div>
);
 }
}
export default Products;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to make `this` refer to the component you can `.bind(this)` the function

```
function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  this.setState({products:response});
}.bind(this)
```

If you can use ES6 then you can also use an arrow function where `this` is automatically bound:

```
(response) => {
  console.log(response);
  this.setState({products:response});
}
```

Comment: Wow, I was getting this wrong my whole evening. The arrow functions carry the this context forward, I didn't know about that. Will dive a little more into ES6! Thanks!